# How to fix overflow error on ListView inside Responsive Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use ListView inside a package called Responsive Container and whenever I use it a White Screen came along and covers all the contain

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ListView shrinkWrap property to true